# fortify migration wizard on opening the merged fpr

Tags: fortify

I am seeing a weird issue on opening the newly merged fpr file. It gives me an error like "this project contains 4.5 style analysis value. This wizard will migrate the project to 6.3 "
Kindly help.
I am able to open the file previous to merge.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

4.5 style analysis values were before SCA 5.0 was released around 2008 (and before the defunct "Fortify 360" product was created, which set the product version back to 1.0.

Unless one of the files you are merging is from the <2008 version of SCA, this error message is unexpected. Contact Fortify Technical Support.